# Nginx. connect() to unix:/tmp/php.socket failed

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

I am trying to setup nginx on my ubuntu vm and trying to host a php website. I am trying to replicate a server setup on my ubuntu vm. I am getting this error when i try to access the php page from my nginx server. I tried to look up for the php.socket file inside the /tmp/ folder but there's nothing in it. is there something wrong with fastcgi or php on my vm.

The complete error is as follows:

```
[crit] 9267#0: *1 connect() to unix:/tmp/php.socket failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.xxx.xxx, server: xxx.xxx.xxx.com, request: "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/tmp/php.socket:", host: "xxx.xxx.xxx..com"
```

please help. I dont know why is this happening am i missing a package or something. I have already got everything installed i guess and have got the same configurations on my local as server.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the unix socket, try to use the TCP\IP Connection:

`location ~ .php$ {
    # fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    # ...
}`

This is for PHP5-FPM (which may be an alternative), maybe you have to use port 7777

Comment: `ERROR: unable to bind listening socket for address '127.0.0.1:9000': Address already in use (98`

Answer (score 1):

i was able to solve the problem by installing:

php-fastcgi.

After it was installed i ran sudo /etc/init.d/php-fastcgi start

Then it created the php.socket inside the /tmp folder which solved the issue. But however now the page which I am trying to open is taking forever to open and in the end it gives an error saying timeout:

> [error] 28830#0: *5 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out)
>   while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.xxx.xxx,
>   server: xxx.xxx.xxx.com, request: "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "fastcgi://unix:/tmp/php.socket:", host: "xxx.xxx.xxx.com"

I tried changing the timeout by changing the value of proxy_read_timeout to `proxy_read_timeout 300`; inside the nginx.conf

But that doesn't seem to correct the problem..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use php5-fpm with socket you should configure  `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` to your needs.

And in nginx config use for example:

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
```

It seems you config of nginx points to a "wrong" (not default) location.

Sockets should be faster then TCP, because no overhead. (Maybe the sockets must be configured correct to give best performance)